# Are dynamically created divs unavailable in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am updating the content of a div depending on what the user clicks. Sometimes I show an image, sometimes I show text:

```
var output;
switch(type)
{
    case IMAGE:
        pages = null;
        contentText = null;
        upArrow = null;
        downArrow = null;

        var imageURL = "assets/images/" + items[itemIndex].imageURL;
        output = '<img src="' + imageURL + '" class="fullImage" />';
        break;

    case TEXT:
        pageIndex = 0;
        pages = items[itemIndex].copy.page;
        numPages = pages.length;
        lastPageIndex = numPages - 1;

        output = '<div id="contentText" class="text"></div>';
        output += '<div id="textUpArrow" class="arrow upArrow"></div>';
        output += '<div id="textDownArrow" class="arrow downArrow"></div>';

        contentText = $("#contentText");

        textUpArrow = $("#textUpArrow");
        textUpArrow.bind(MOUSE_DOWN, onUpArrowClicked);

        textDownArrow = $("#textDownArrow");
        textDownArrow.bind(MOUSE_DOWN, onDownArrowClicked);

        setText();
        break;
}
content.html(output);
```

The issue seems to be about scope. I declared the contentText, textUpArrow and textDownArrow at the root level of my JS file (I don't know if it's called root, but it's outside every function, so it's available globally).

What happens is when I output the said variables in the console, nothing is undefined. However, whenever I try to use these vars, wether for the event listeners or for changing their CSS via jQuery, nothing happens.

What should I look into? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding an event to `div` **before** it's been added to the DOM.
That's not going to work.

Comment: Yes! That was exactly it! I didn't think they would not be referred to, but since jQuery targets what is in the DOM, it makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.bind()`. From jQuery [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) documentation:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the
>   `.bind()` method is used for attaching an event handler directly to
>   elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in
>   the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call
>   to `.bind()` occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion
>   of event delegation in [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate).

Comment: Ah, I don't know this way, I will look into it, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

when is the output being applied to the Document?

if it is in setText() you may want to call that method after you are finished with the output text and prior to setting the contentText.

When you try to set that variable, there is no div in the document with that ID.

Comment: I reordered the functions indeed, and that fixed my issue. It seems I was referring to the divs before there where in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you set the `contentText`, `textUpArrow` and `textDownArrow` before the elements are created.

```
output = '<div id="contentText" class="text"></div>';
output += '<div id="textUpArrow" class="arrow upArrow"></div>';
output += '<div id="textDownArrow" class="arrow downArrow"></div>';

contentText = $("#contentText");
```

Here, `contentText` is set to the element with element id `#contentText`, but the element is not created yet so it becomes undefined